# Singleton WatchServiceHandler class doesn't print

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton, watchservice

I have a singleton `Handler` class that is instantiated like this:

```
public static synchronized Singleton getInstance()
{
    if (instance == null)
        instance = new Singleton();

    return instance;
}
```

At the creation it creates a couple of classes that contain a WatchService and process events from that WatchService (using an infinite loop and .take())

When I have a main method that does this:

```
public void print(){
    System.out.println("test");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Singleton s = Singleton.getInstance();
    s.print(); 
}
```

Nothing is printed! I assume it has something to do with the watchservice. But I thought that automatically runs in a different thread.

Comment: WatchService will hold the flow. You need to run the watch service in a different thread.

Comment: Correct instantiation of Singletons: `static final Singleton = new Singleton();` Everything else is prone to thread issues.